# Convert Table Column to Comma Separated String

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, iterator, concatenation, collect

ArcGis Pro 3.0.2

Is there a way to use native tools to convert a column in my Table to a long String where values at separated by a comma? e.g.

```
my column
1
2
3
```

Becomes `"1,2,3"`

I tried using `Iterate Field Values` combined with `Collect Values` in Model Builder. The model will go from 0 to 100% in a few seconds, but then it just hangs at 100% indefinitely (my table is only 2,000 rows). Perhaps I'm not using the iterator or collect values function correctly? Screenshot below.

[image: model builder]

I want to pass this long string to another tool / model for additional processing.

I am hoping for a **NON**-python / script solution.

Comment: I would look at using [Transpose Fields (Data Management) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/transpose-fields.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a Calculate value tool with a few lines of python code using a search cursor to build your comma separated string, that in my mind would be the most efficient, scalable and understandable approach.

This model would do the concatenation of the numeric values as you require:

[image: Model]

The Calculate tool is:

[image: Tool]

Code block:

```py
import arcpy
def concatID(layer,field):
    aSet = set()
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer,field) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            aSet.add(str(row[0]))
            
    text = ",".join(aSet)
    return text
```

But you have *explicitly* asked for a model builder approach using only tools, so here is a solution:

[image: Model]

The tools are set up as below:

[image: Tools]

The issue with this approach is that the temporary table creates a row for each feature in the input dataset. This will not scale well with very large datasets, if that is your intention? I would recommend you take the python route.

Comment: Great answer, accepted for the Python solution. For some reason Dissolve keeps giving me the dreaded 99999 errors. Is there a dissolve alternative for standalone tables? Since the dissolve requires feature class.